# How can I avoid using eval() for the base object

Tags: javascript, eval

As I understand it, eval() can be harmful. And it's annoying seeing all the warnings in my JSLint.

I've got a number of functions that are identical for my Wishlist / Shopping Cart. So I'd like to make it dynamic and only have one function of each.

Instead of `cart.addItem()` and `wish.addItem()`, I want `cartWish.addItem(type)`.

Inside of `cartWish.addItem()` I need to access `cart.data` or `wish.data`, depending on the type argument.

How can I do this without resorting to `eval(type).data`?

I tried `this[type].data` and it didn't seem to work right.

Comment: How about `addItem(target)` where `target` can be `cart` or `wish`?

Comment: Why not keep it simple.  `if(type === 'wish'){ wish.data; } else if(type === 'cart'){ cart.data; }` :-)

Comment: @thg435: You mean pass in the `cart` or `wish` objects instead of a string?

Comment: `eval` is something you use when you tried like 1000 different things and there seems to be no other viable option. Please please please refrain from it. It shouldn't that hard to solve this problem without eval.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: exactly.

Comment: You show a bit too little code to actually show what would be a good solution, but `eval` definitely is not the answer here.

Comment: @thg435: That's a good idea :)

Comment: clear. requirement for prototyping both wish and cart from an abstract object with an abstract "add" method. then  you don't Need to care about the particular instance since it will have an add method (or a stubb)

Comment: The reason I don't use simple if statements is because I don't want to copy the object. In other cases, like product lists the objects can get quite huge and I only want one in memory.

And they are used often in the functions so it would be a nightmare to use an if statement every time I wanted to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was poor programming on my part. I didn't know that JavaScript tended to make references of objects instead of copies.

So doing...

```
var myReference=(type == "cart") ? cart.data : wish.data;
myReference[0].name="Bob Dole's Grill";
```

... will actually change cart.data[0].name outside of the function. And it will do so without making a copy of the cart object in memory.

Note: You could also just pass in the object by reference into the function, but I'm not sure if I can, because I'm sometimes invoking this function from a KnockoutJS click event.

Answer (score 1):

What's the difference between

```
cart.addItem(...);
wish.addItem(...)
```

and

```
cartWish.addItem("cart", ...);
cartWish.addItem("wish", ...);
```

Seems like the same number of lines of code, and then all you've done is obfuscate what you are really doing. Maybe create a function that takes either a cart or wish object and assume they have the same interface:

```
function addItem(x, data) {
    x.addItem(data);
}

var cart = ...
var wish = ...

addItem(cart, {...});
addItem(wish, {...});
```

Another option is to create a class:

```
function Item(type) {
    this.type = type;
}

Item.prototype.add = function add(...) {
    // ...
};


var cart = new Item("cart");
var wish = new Item("wish");

cart.add(...)
wish.add(...)
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid making a copy of the object (they are big) at all, but this may be the best solution; since the object will get destroyed as soon as the function finishes execution.

Comment: I just read somewhere that passing an object into a function passes it by reference automatically. Is that true? If so, I'll just pass in the object instead of a string saying "cart" or "wish".